# Storing PHP 5.3 sessions into PostgreSQL 8.4

Tags: php, postgresql, session

I'm using CentOS 6.0 Linux 64 bit with the stock packages:

```
# rpm -qa|grep php
php-cli-5.3.2-6.el6_0.1.x86_64
php-5.3.2-6.el6_0.1.x86_64
php-xml-5.3.2-6.el6_0.1.x86_64
php-pgsql-5.3.2-6.el6_0.1.x86_64
php-pear-1.9.0-2.el6.noarch
php-pdo-5.3.2-6.el6_0.1.x86_64
php-common-5.3.2-6.el6_0.1.x86_64

# rpm -qa|grep postgres
postgresql-devel-8.4.7-1.el6_0.1.x86_64
postgresql-docs-8.4.7-1.el6_0.1.x86_64
postgresql-libs-8.4.7-1.el6_0.1.x86_64
postgresql-8.4.7-1.el6_0.1.x86_64
postgresql-server-8.4.7-1.el6_0.1.x86_64
```

and would like to change my own PHP script from using
**$_SERVER['REMOTE_USER']** to using **$_SESSION**,
but don't have any experience with PHP sessions yet.

I'd like the (quite extensive) user data to be stored into
the PostgreSQL and only save a "user id" in $_SESSION.

However [this doc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session-pgsql.installation.php) says "This extension is considered unmaintained and dead".

Does anybody please have any advice, what to do here?

Maybe I can save session data into the db myself (and how)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override PHP's session save/load handlers with your own: http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php

This lets you save the session data to a database, or chip it onto a stone tablet if you'd like. The choice of underlying storage medium/database is irrelevant, as long as your code sends/receives the session data properly.

Comment: Example code: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php#104847

Comment: Thank you, I wonder if anyone has done it for PostgreSQL yet as I'd hate to "reinvent the wheel"?

Comment: Probably, but it's not exactly hard to do. it's probably 50 lines of code at most. connection code + save session + load session + remove stale sessions. It's not particularly complicated. Check out hakre's link for the skeleton framework.

Answer (score 0):

Simple flat version :

```
sql("INSERT INTO sessions (session,userid) VALUES('".json_encode($_SESSION["toomuchuserinfo"])."','".$_SESSION['userid']."');");
$r=sql("SELECT session FROM sessions where userid='".$_SESSION['userid']."';");
$_SESSION["toomuchuserinfo"]=json_decode($r[0][0]);
```